# Проблема с кодировкой html письма на mail.ru

Tags: php, кодировка, mail.ru, phpmailer

Есть php скрипт, отправляющий данные на e-mail заказчика. Проверял работу на яндекс почте и gmail, все отлично. На mail.ru кракозябры вместо русских символов, кодировка указана явно в теле письма, в хэдере письма, в хэдере страницы. Пробовал utf-8, win-1251, win-1252, koi8-r меняется вид символов, но нормальный русский текст так и не отображается. Использую класс phpmailer для авторизации и отправки письма. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы кириллица корректно отображалась в ящиках mail.ru нужно контент конвертировать в windows-1251.
Также проверьте чтобы в конце строки подключающей кодировку был символ перевода строи.

```
$body.="Content-type: text/html; charset=\"windows-1251\"\n";
```

Символ \n в конце обязателен. Вообще без предоставления кода шапки тяжело сказать в чем проблема.
Еще одно уточнение в какой кодировке страница с которой отправляете письмо? Страница должна быть в той же кодировке в которой вы отправляете письмо.